# How to 7zip multiple folders in to one 7z package?

Tags: 7-zip

Let's say there are 3 folders:

```
/a/1
/b/1
/c/1
```

And any of the folders may contain sub folders like

```
/a/1/x
/b/1/y
...
```

How to compress /a/1 /b/1 /c/1 folder with files and sub folders into same one 7z file and keep path info well in the package?

Comment: Are you interested in learning it through the cmd interface, or is using explorer enough?

Comment: Command line preferred.

Comment: `7z a FOLDER_NAME.zip FOLDER_1/* FOLDER_2/* FOLDER_3/*` This will work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
7za a Test a b c
```

will create Test.7z with the three folders and all sub-folders and files stored using relative paths.

If you want to store the folders beginning at the second level, you can use:

```
7za a Test a\1 b\1 c\1
```

Comment: 7za.exe is the command line version. You can use 7z.exe too, assuming you use Windows.

Comment: I've tried (p7za) 7za a Test a\1 b\1 c\1, it says Duplicate filename: 1 1 (Yes, a b c is not acceptable because they contain other files no need to package, the problem is there are folders with the same name 1).

Comment: @Al3n: Do you want to preserve the entire depth of the tree structure or just the local structure?  If you store the full path for each stored directory, you avoid the duplicate names problem, but unzipping gives you either the original structure depth or no structure, so you couldn't retain the local structure attached to a different directory.  If that's a problem, consider zipping each local tree separately to avoid the name duplication, and then zip the zip files into one umbrella file.

Comment: @Al3n: I tested both commands with 7za.exe and they work with no such error. Could be a p7za limitation perhaps, although I can't understand why it's complaining about duplicate *filenames* when they're actually folders.

Comment: @fixer1234 Keep the structure under "1" would be Ok. I originally compress them in different zip packages. I'm wandering put folders in one package to utilize solid compression to reduce total size.

Comment: @Karan I've got success. Thanks. I was using absolute path(OS X 10.10.2, path is like /Volumes/xxx/a/1) firstly. There's no error while using relative path.

Comment: @Al3n: Ah, in [your comment above](http://superuser.com/questions/900911/how-to-7zip-multiple-folders-in-to-one-7z-package/900915?noredirect=1#comment1207842_900915) you used relative paths, and so did I in my answer. If you'd indicated you were using absolute paths that might have raised some flags. Anyway good you managed to solve it.

Comment: @Karan My bad. I should use the same sample paths instead of abstractions.